# GPS координаты из exif

Tags: python, gps, координаты, exif

Получаю из метаданных фотографии gps координаты

```
def get_coords(dir,im_list):
f = open(dir + im_list[0], 'rb')
tags = exifread.process_file(f)
```

Вывод:

```
GPS GPSLatitude [46, 17, 241143/6250]
GPS GPSLongitude [119, 43, 1328511/25000]
```

Если смотреть просто в системе данные изображения, то координаты там показаны так:

```
Coordinates: 46,292603 N / -119,729950 W (426m)
```

Почему питон выводит координаты по другому? Как их понять?

Comment: В файле записаны минуты, а там, где вы смотрите - сотые доли градуса. Наверное, так.

Comment: Что-то не сходится. Из `[46, 17, 241143/6250]` должно получаться `46.2940508`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использовал либу GPSPhoto

```
d=gpsphoto.getGPSData(dir+im_list[0])
```

Вывод

```
{'Latitude': 46.2945286, 'Longitude': -119.73191200000001, 'Altitude':   477.327}
```

Уже норм получилось